# What does $[T]^b_a$ mean, for $T$ a linear transformation, $a=\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$, $b=\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$, and $x_i$ and $y_i$ all vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What does this symbolism mean?

$$[T]^b_a$$
where $T$ is a linear transformation, $a=\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$, $b=\{y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n\}$, and $\{x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n, y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_n\}$ are all vectors.

Thank you.

**Edit since it was requested**; T$\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}$= $\begin{pmatrix}x-y+z\\ x-y\\ x+2z\end{pmatrix}$,

a={(1,1,1), (1,0,1), (0,0,1)}, b={(1,0,-1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1).

It asks me to find $[T]^b_a$. I have posted in comments what I think he wants and what I tried but it is not the right answer so I propapbly did not understand the question)

Comment: I feel that this could only mean one of two things. Either, $Ta = b$ or $Tb = a$. I'd assume the former... doesn't your text use an example to show this in action somewhere?

Comment: The notation makes sense if $a$ and $b$ are bases. Then $[T]_a^b$ is the matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t. $a$ and $b$: $\Big[ [T(x_1)]_b \ [T(x_2)]_b \ \cdots [T(x_n)]_b \Big]$ where $[T(x_i)]_b$ is the coordinates of $T(x_i)$ expressed in the basis of $b$ i.e. $T(x_i) = \sum_{j = 1}^n t_{ij} y_j$.

Comment: [Relevant Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector#Basis_transformation_matrix)

Comment: Well the question asks me to find the matrix T. However this is the second requirement of a question and in the first  requirement he gave me the matrix T(x,y,x)=(x-y-z, x-y, x+2z). He then request me to find a matrix A so that Tx=Ax. I did find him since it was easy. However I dont understant what I have to do in the second requiremnet, since he already gave me this matrix. Do I have to find a new one? or he is just refering to a different matrix but uses the same letter T?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include all the information you have?

Comment: What I thought the question asks is to find the matrix P that connects the spans of a and b, so that B=P$^-1$AP where B the matrix with the columns that consists of vectors of b and A matrix of vectors of a. However that matrix P is not the right answer so I propably did not understand the question.

Comment: Never mind I think I found where I was wrong. It is what  @ayeayemaung  says. It is T(a)=c where c vector space that can be written as vectors of b. https://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/linear-algebra/matrix-linear-trans/matrix-linear-trans.html. Here is a link of an example, because it is much easier that way to understand it than pure mathematic symbolism.